# Cannot find symbol (object) -- Why?

Tags: java

[Solved] -- Thanks everyone! Got it!

I am getting an error in line 8: "Cannot find symbol" in JavaBeans.

I am also getting one in line 16 that can't find variable SetAge, and JCreator also has a problem with this line that says: "Operator + cannot be applied to Person.getAge.int".

I think I may have done the package wrong or something that is causing my main class file not seeing my other class file.  Could anyone help?  Thanks!
(sorry messy post)

package persontestdebug;

public class PersonTestDebug{

```
public static void main( String args[] ){

Person person1 = Person( "Susan", "Beal", 19 );

System.out.printf( "Created %s %s, age %d\n", person1.getFirstName(), person1.getLastName(), person1.getAge() );

System.out.println( person1.getFirstName()+" is" +person1.getAge()+" years old.");

System.out.printf( "Happy Birthday to %s %s\n", person1.getFirstName(), person1.getLastName() );

person1.setAge = person1.getAge() + 1;

System.out.println( "This person is now "+person1.getAge()+" years old.");

} // end main
```

} // end class PersonTestDebug

-------------- and the other class:

package persontestdebug;

public class Person{

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private int years;

public void Person( String first, String last, int years ){
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
        if ( years > 0 ){
        age = years;
        }
} // end Person constructor


public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
} // end method getFirstName
public void setFirstName( String first ){
    firstName = first;
} // end method setFirstName

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
} // end method getLastName
public void setLastName( String last ){
    lastName = last;
} // end method setLastName

public int getAge(){
    return age;
} // end method getAge
public void setAge( int years ){
    if ( years > 0 ){
    age = years;
    }
} // end method setAge
```

} // end class Person

Answer (score 1):

`Person person1 = Person( "Susan", "Beal", 19 );` should be `Person person1 = new Person( "Susan", "Beal", 19 );`

Answer (score -1):

public void Person( String first, String last, int years ) should 
public Person( String first, String last, int years )